# Массовая рассылка с помощью telethon. Вопрос по оптимизации

Tags: python, telethon, рассылка

Не смотря на то, что само сообщение изменяется случайным образом каждому следующему пользователю, и стоит случайная задержка - мут прилетает примерно через 10 отосланных сообщений. Прошу дать несколько советов по возможной оптимизации кода, дабы аккаунт для рассылки жил дольше.

P.S. Списки для рассылки импортируются из другого модуля, но, не думаю, что он тут нужен.

Вот, собственно, код:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
import time
import random
from read_csv import tel_usernames, sent_usernames


def sent_users_data(text_file, username):
    with open(text_file, 'a') as file:
        file.write(username + '\n')


api_id = my_ap_id
api_hash = 'my_api_hash'
phone_number = 'my_phone_number'

client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash,
                        system_version='4.16.30-vxCUSTOM')

client.start()

random_words = {
    'hello_choice': ['Привет', 'Привет!', 'Здравствуйте', 'Здравствуйте!', 'Приветствую', 'Приветствую!'],
    'heart_choice': ['❤️', '❤️❤️', '❤️❤️❤️'],
    'we_choice': ['Мы с тобой', 'Ты и я', 'Мы вместе'],
    'chat_choice': ['подписаны на один мамский чат', 'состоим в одном мамском чате', 'являемся подписчиками одного мамского чата'],
    'doula_choice': ['акушерки', 'акушерки и доулы', 'доулы'],
    'she_is_choice': ['Она еще и', 'Она, к тому же,', 'Кроме того, она']

}

usernames = tel_usernames

for username in usernames:
    message = f'{random.choice(random_words["hello_choice"])}\
    {random.choice(random_words["heart_choice"])}\
    {random.choice(random_words["we_choice"])}\
    {random.choice(random_words["chat_choice"])}, не могу не поделиться с тобой каналом моей\
    {random.choice(random_words["doula_choice"])}! \
    {random.choice(random_words["she_is_choice"])} консультант по грудному вскармливанию. https://t.me/tkachevakb'
    try:
        if username not in sent_usernames:
            sent_msg = client.send_message(username, message)
            sent_users_data('sent.txt', username)
            print(f'Доставлено пользователю {username}')
    except:
        sent_users_data('sent.txt', username + ' denied')
        print(f'Не доставлено пользователю {username}')
    finally:
        print('Ожидаем...')
        time.sleep(random.randrange(181, 247))
        print('Переходим к следующему пользователю...')


client.disconnect()
```

Comment: Не советую работать с `txt` файлами как с БД. Они не поддерживают многопоточность. Рекомендую `SQLite3`

Comment: Полностью согласен. Но прежде, чем переходить к бд и многопоточности, мне хотелось бы чтобы код выполнял свою основную задачу лучше, чем сейчас. А затем уже и все остальное.